# Compress-Archive is throwing 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: powershell

While running below PowerShell command remotely to compress the folder into zip format, getting 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

```bsh
PS > Compress-Archive -Path \\myserver1\Backup\8159 -DestinationPath \\myserver1\Backup\8159.zip
```

While running the same command as shown below in myserver1 machine directly then getting `Exception calling "Write" with "3" argument(s): "Stream was too long."`

```bsh
PS > Compress-Archive -Path E:\Backup\8159 -DestinationPath E:\Backup\8159.zip
```

I verified below as well

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB
```

```
WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Shell

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   MaxMemoryPerShellMB                            2147483647
```

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB
```

```
WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Plugin\microsoft.powershell\Quotas

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   MaxMemoryPerShellMB                            2147483647
```

Could anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can find the PowerShell solution using `IO.Compression` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72607926/how-do-i-compress-files-using-powershell-that-are-over-2-gb)

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6), the Compress-Archive cmdlet relies upon the Microsoft .NET API [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.7.2) to compress files.

It states that *"Therefore, the maximum file size that is 2 GB. This is a limitation of the underlying API."*

You will get this error if the data to compress is over that limit.

Perhaps you should better use use 7Zip. 
You can find a module [7Zip4Powershell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/7Zip4Powershell/1.9.0) in the PSGallery.